# Background mode for static library

Tags: iphone

i am developing one application.In that i am using my own static library with location service.So I need to run the app in background continuously.For that i have to mention the UIBackgroundMode in plist file.Here my doubt is all location service code is in library,and that library didn't have plist file.If i mention that UIBackGroundMode in my app plist file then app is running in background or not.

Comment: A static library only executes as part of the app it's built into.  When the app runs, there's no important difference between having been built with a static library or entirely from source files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set your app to get location updates the CLLocationManager you are using will receive updates when the app is in the background.

Comment: Ok.I know that one.My doubt is Where can i put UIBAckgroundMode in main app plist file or any other place.

Comment: It is the responsibility of the app to inform what backgroundmodes that it wants to use so you can only put it in the main app's plist file.